# primefaes submenu and layout

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a layout and I need to show a JSF page in the center position when a menu item is selected, and if I select other menu item it must change to this and so on. I dont know how to do this, all the pages must appear in the center position acording to the selection in the menu (left position)

```
<p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50"  resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="false">  
    <h:outputText value="South unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>  

<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="280" header="start" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="false">
        <p:panelMenu style="width:100%"> 
            <p:submenu label="clinet maneger" id="panelMenu" >  

                <p:menuitem value="basic"   
                url="/pages/basicInfo.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document" /> 

                <p:menuitem value="clinets information"  
                url="/pages/clinets.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document"/>
                <p:menuitem value="ernterprises Information"  
                url="/pages/enterprises.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document"/>
            </p:submenu>  
            <p:separator />  
        </p:panelMenu>  
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center" resizable="true">
        <ui:insert name="center"></ui:insert>
        <ui:include src="/pages/clinetsList.xhtml"></ui:include>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444584/primefaces-page-layout-with-tree-menu-as-navigation/10445869#10445869